# Se pierden los iconos de la aplicación al ejecutarla desde diferente sitio al que fue compilada

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una aplicación en Qt compilada de forma estática. Tiene su fichero de recursos que apunta a un directorio bajo el directorio en el que se encuentra el directorio de trabajo, con el main.cpp, el archivo .pro etc.
Algo así:

```
Proyecto
|-main.cpp
|-mainwindows.h
|-mainwindows.cpp    
|-..........
|-iconos.qrc
|-/Iconos|-icono1.png
|-/Iconos|-icono2.png
|-/Iconos|............
etc
```

El contenido del archivo iconos.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Iconos/trucking.png</file>
        <file>Iconos/engineer.png</file>
        <file>Iconos/brick.png</file>
        <file>Iconos/delete.png</file>
        <file>Iconos/file.png</file>
        <file>Iconos/folder.png</file>
        <file>Iconos/sinclasificar.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

En el archivo *.pro tengo incluido el fichero:

```
RESOURCES += \    
    iconos.qrc
```

Y la forma de llamarlos (este es uno de ellos):

```
QIcon icono ("../Proyecto/Iconos/brick.png");
QPushButton* buton = new QPushButton(icono,"");
```

También he de decir que los iconos de la barra de tareas no tienen ese problema. Son unos iconos que aparecen en unas tablas, tanto dentro de unas celdas como en un layout dentro del mainwindows

El caso es que al compilar desde Qt Creator, no tengo problemas, pero al ejecutar la aplicación desde fuera, ya no guarda la ruta de los iconos.
Viendo esto: 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html interpreto que hay que poner al comienzo la macro `Q_INIT_RESORUCE(nombre_del_archivo_qrc_sin_extension)` pero no obtengo nada.
Siempre puedo copiar el directorio con los iconos bajo el ejecutable, pero entiendo que no es la solución.

Entonces la duda es...¿cómo incorporar los iconos al ejecutable para que siempre estén disponibles?

Comment: ¿Cómo usas los iconos en la aplicación?

Comment: ¿ Has creado el archivo de recursos con los iconos, o los estás cargando usando la ruta física al archivo ?

Comment: Hola @eferion. He añadido datos a la pregunta porque realmente estaba muy mal formulada.

Comment: Hola @Juanjo. Pues si no me equivoco, estoy haciendo las dos cosas. Es decir, he creado el archivo de recursos y también estoy cargando la ruta del archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto está mal:

```
QIcon icono ("../Proyecto/Iconos/brick.png");
QPushButton* buton = new QPushButton(icono,"");
```

Porque no estás usando los iconos del archivo de recursos sino que los cargas directamente del sistema de archivos.

Dado que los recursos los estás cargando así:

```
<RCC>
 <qresource prefix="/">
 <file>Iconos/brick.png</file>
 ...
```

La carga del recurso sería:

```
 QIcon icono (":/Iconos/brick.png");
```

Los dos puntos del inicio indican que la carga es desde un recurso. La ruta es la que se indica en el campo `<file>`

Comment: Arreglado. Eso era!